# QueryInterface(cinsIFileURL) returns nothing - Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was following some examples to load a dll in firefox extension using js-ctypes. It works except the following code:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require('chrome');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
const ResProtocolHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
var data = self.data;
var dataUrl = data.url("MyBin.dll");
var file = Services.io.newURI(dataUrl, null, null);
console.log(file);
file = ResProtocolHandler.resolveURI(file);
console.log(file);
file = Services.io.newURI(file, null, null);
console.log(file);
file = file.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL);
console.log(file);
```

What I get is as follow:

```
console.log: smartt: {"spec":"resource://smartt/data/MyBin.dll","prePath":"resource://smartt","scheme":"resource","userPass":"","username":"","password":"","hostPort":"smartt","host":"smartt","port":-1,"path":"/data/MyBin.dll","asciiSpec":"resource://smartt/data/MyBin.dll","asciiHostPort":"smartt","asciiHost":"smartt","originCharset":"UTF-8","ref":"","specIgnoringRef":"resource://smartt/data/MyBin.dll","hasRef":false}
console.log: smartt: file:///C:/Users/dipto/AppData/Local/Temp/417dcdc0-7016-4975-8344-4c43fe7cc83c/extensions/@smartt/data/MyBin.dll
console.log: smartt: {"spec":"file:///C:/Users/dipto/AppData/Local/Temp/417dcdc0-7016-4975-8344-4c43fe7cc83c/extensions/@smartt/data/MyBin.dll","prePath":"file://","scheme":"file","userPass":"","username":"","password":"","hostPort":"","host":"","port":-1,"path":"/C:/Users/dipto/AppData/Local/Temp/417dcdc0-7016-4975-8344-4c43fe7cc83c/extensions/@smartt/data/MyBin.dll","asciiSpec":"file:///C:/Users/dipto/AppData/Local/Temp/417dcdc0-7016-4975-8344-4c43fe7cc83c/extensions/@smartt/data/MyBin.dll","asciiHostPort":"","asciiHost":"","originCharset":"UTF-8","ref":"","specIgnoringRef":"file:///C:/Users/dipto/AppData/Local/Temp/417dcdc0-7016-4975-8344-4c43fe7cc83c/extensions/@smartt/data/MyBin.dll","hasRef":false}
console.log: smartt: {spec:..,prePath:..,scheme:..,userPass:..,username:..,password:..,hostPort:..,host:..,port:..,path:..,equals:..,schemeIs:..,clone:..,resolve:..,asciiSpec:..,asciiHostPort:..,asciiHost:..,originCharset:..,ref:..,equalsExceptRef:..,cloneIgnoringRef:..,specIgnoringRef:..,hasRef:..,filePath:..,query:..,directory:..,fileName:..,fileBaseName:..,fileExtension:..,getCommonBaseSpec:..,getRelativeSpec:..,file:.., }
```

As you see, the last output is empty. I expected a file url. My goal is to get the local file path of the resource file.

Will someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something very silly?

Comment: Is your addon marked as `unpack:true` in package.json?

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, it is. I can see the file present in there, all the other values seems correct. just the `file.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL);` making everything empty.

Comment: Btw: instead of using `Cu.import` you can use `require` directly. It will return an object with the exported vars as properties to it (so like passing an empty object as second param to `Cu.import`)